# iPhone AppStore's UITableViewCell background colours

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, app-store

I wanted to test out some different coloured cells in my iPhone App, and I thought that the same coloured cells as the app store ones would probably suit. Therefore I wanted to try them out. Unfortunately I do not have the colour codes for the cells, does anyone know?

These are the colours in action:

[image: http://reviews.cnet.com/i/bto/20080710/AppStore3.png]

Also, would this code be correct to show them?

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ( indexPath.row%2 == 0) { 
UIColor *altCellColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:256/256.0 green:237/256.0 blue:227/256.0 alpha:1.0]; /
cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor;
}
if ( indexPath.row%2 == 1) {
UIColor *altCellColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1alpha:1.0];
cell.backgroundColor = altCellColor2;
}
```

Comment: You may want to create those colors once and reuse them, rather than creating them every time a cell will display, for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks like it'll work. The two colors you're looking for are

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:.678 green:.678 blue:.69 alpha:1]
```

and

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:.596 green:.596 blue:.612 alpha:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on mac then, just search fo `Digital Color Meter` in spotlight(this app in Application's utility). This application will give you any RGB and other color code value that you want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. it's worked for me

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:172.0/255.0 green:217.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1]
```